# displaying nav correctly

Tags: html, internet-explorer

If I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">[logo]</div>
    <div id="navigation" class="cf">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Active Tab</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dolor link two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Here is a link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I style just the `<div id="navigation" class="cf">` will that display correctly on IE<9 or will having a `nav` element mess up the rendering?

Comment: How does this apply to the question:? `It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.` The answer is a yes or no

Comment: So what did it do when you tried it?

Comment: Dear you should as the question in which you are facing problem, here you are asking your requirement. Lets try first yourself and then ask question, even you will feel good once you try by yourself.

Comment: @HappySingh: I don't have IE8 or IE7

Comment: You have Developer Tools (F12), and so the ability to change the browser mode to IE7/8. In 99% of cases IE9's browser modes match the real browsers.

Comment: Ahh.. thats the issue.. hmm you can download from microsoft's site.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft offers [Virtual PC for free](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) along with [free HDD image downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575) for accurate browser testing down to IE 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use an [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) in order to have the `nav` element inserted into the DOM. Also, nav as a block element. Therefore, you will need to explicitly add `nav { display: block; }` in your CSS.